# Error "Server failed to start" while running JBoss 7.1 in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

I have a problem installing and running JBoss AS 7.1.0 via JBoss Tools version 3.3 in Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo). I created a new server runtime environment:
Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime environments
JBoss AS root directory (mine was C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final) select the "Create a new local server".

Create a server:
File->New->Other->Server->Server->JBoss Community->JBoss AS 7.x
Select my newly created runtime configuration, click next and finish.

I tried to Run server for testing but Eclipse throw some kind of error. Here the information from "Error log":

Server JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server failed to start.

**eclipse.buildId**=M20120208-0800

**java.version**=1.6.0_31

**java.vendor**=Sun Microsystems Inc.

**BootLoader constants:** OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU

**Framework arguments:**  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

**Command-line arguments:** -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issue on Windows. We fixed this by using JBoss AS 7.1.1 instead of 7.1.0. Probably you also need to do [this workaround](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/11/24/jboss-as-71-beta1-with-jboss-tools--use-web-port-poller). But I assume this is not necessary, because you already use Version 3.3 of the JBoss Tools.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen when you try to start Jboss with java version > 1.7
Could you try upgrading your java